# Rails helper functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where can I find a complete list of Rails helper functions (such as form_for)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of them are under ActionView::Helpers in documentation.

- [javascript helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html)
- [form helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)
- [url helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html)
- [tag helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html)
- [asset tag helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html)
- [date helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html)

There are more available, so downloading Rails source and looking under action_view/helpers is likely your best bet.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a brand new beginner to Rails, and don't exactly know how to download the Rails source and find that information.

Comment: You can download or browse the source of the current stable version of Rails (2.3.x) here: http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/2-3-stable

Answer (score 0):

ApiDock is a pretty good source of documentation.  Check out http://apidock.com/rails/browse under `ActionView::Helpers`.

Also Obie Fernandez's book "The Rails Way" has a comprehensive (I believe) chapter on them.

Comment: It looks like Chapter 11 covers helpers in detail. The full text of the book is on safaribooksonline.com, for those with subscriptions.